# Exception calling spring data jpa query method with suffix "IN" against primitive type on openjpa

Tags: java, spring, openjpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following jpa data query method:

```
findByEntityIdIn(List<Long> entities);
```

And on my persistent object I have a long type persisent field called "entityId".

When I call this method on openjpa I get the following exception...

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Filter invalid. Cannot compare field entityId of type long to value of type java.util.Collection. Numeric comparisons must be between numeric types only. To enable such comparisons for backwards-compatibility, add "QuotedNumbersInQueries=true" to the org.apache.openjpa.Compatibility setting in your configuration.; nested exception is  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Filter invalid. Cannot compare field entityId of type long to value of type java.util.Collection. Numeric comparisons must be between numeric types only. To enable such comparisons for backwards-compatibility, add "QuotedNumbersInQueries=true" to the org.apache.openjpa.Compatibility setting in your configuration.

Should I just do what it recommends or is there another solution? Basically it sounds like I can only use collections against string data types without the configuration parameter as it quotes each entry in the passed in collection.

Comment: Is entityId a field on your entity class?  What is its type?

Comment: it is and it's type is Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2018) in OpenJPA. We recommend to use a different persistence provider.